# Need to create a Dataframe where the columns are created by looping through the values of another Dataframe columns. How can I do this in PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to get the column names and the data types of each column from the original Dataframe "User_df" into their own columns where the values of the columns are the column names and datatypes respectively.

I have 88 Columns and about 9500 Rows.

The below code works when I try to create a Dataframe with one column ("ColumnDataTypes") but not when I try to do it for both columns:

```
col_types = User_df.dtypes

col_types2, col_types3 = [items[:] for items in zip(*col_types)]

rdd_col_names = sc.parallelize(col_types2)

rdd_col_types = sc.parallelize(col_types3)

row_rdd_col_names = rdd_col_names.map(lambda x: Row(x))

row_rdd_col_types = rdd_col_types.map(lambda x: Row(x))

data1 = row_rdd_col_names

data2 = row_rdd_col_types

schema3 = StructType([StructField("ColumnDataTypes", StringType(), True)])

new_dataframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data2, schema3)

new_dataframe.show()

+---------------+
|ColumnDataTypes|
+---------------+
|string         |
|date           |
|int            |
|int            |
|int            |
|int            |
|int            |
|double         |
|double         |
|double         |
|double         |
|int            |
|int            |
|int            |
|int            |
|int            |
|int            |
|int            |
|double         |
|int            |
|double         |
|int            |
|int            |
|double         |
|int            |
|double         |
|int            |
|int            |
|double         |
|double         |
|double         |
|double         |
|double         |
|double         |
|double         |
|int            |
|int            |
|int            |
|int            |
|double         |
|int            |
|double         |
|int            |
|int            |
|int            |
|double         |
|double         |
|int            |
|double         |
|int            |
|double         |
|double         |
|int            |
|double         |
|double         |
|int            |
|double         |
|double         |
|int            |
|double         |
|double         |
|int            |
|double         |
|double         |
|int            |
|string         |
|int            |
|string         |
|string         |
|int            |
|string         |
|string         |
|string         |
|double         |
|string         |
|string         |
|string         |
|string         |
|int            |
|string         |
|boolean        |
|string         |
|int            |
|boolean        |
|boolean        |
|string         |
|string         |
|string         |
+---------------+
```

Below is the code to get both columns into one dataframe but it gives me an error:

```
# Get each Columns name and data type from the original Dataframe 
"User_df":

col_types = User_df.dtypes

col_types2, col_types3 = [items[:] for items in zip(*col_types)]

rdd_col_names = sc.parallelize(col_types2)

rdd_col_types = sc.parallelize(col_types3)

row_rdd_col_names = rdd_col_names.map(lambda x: Row(x))

row_rdd_col_types = rdd_col_types.map(lambda x: Row(x))

data = [[row_rdd_col_names], [row_rdd_col_types]]

schema = StructType([StructField("ColumnNames", StringType(), True), 
                     StructField("ColumnDataTypes", StringType(), True)
                    ])

new_dataframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, schema) 

display(new_dataframe)
```

This is the error the above code gives me:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_16479/193552006.py in <module>
     26 # StructType([StructField("ColumnDataTypes", StringType(), True)])
     27 
---> 28 new_dff0 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, schema)
     29 
     30 

/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/context.py in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    367         Py4JJavaError: ...
    368         """
--> 369         return self.sparkSession.createDataFrame(data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    370 
    371     def registerDataFrameAsTable(self, df, tableName):

/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    673             return super(SparkSession, self).createDataFrame(
    674                 data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
--> 675         return self._create_dataframe(data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    676 
    677     def _create_dataframe(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema):

/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py in _create_dataframe(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    698             rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data.map(prepare), schema, samplingRatio)
    699         else:
--> 700             rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
    701         jrdd = self._jvm.SerDeUtil.toJavaArray(rdd._to_java_object_rdd())
    702         jdf = self._jsparkSession.applySchemaToPythonRDD(jrdd.rdd(), schema.json())

/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py in _createFromLocal(self, data, schema)
    507         # make sure data could consumed multiple times
    508         if not isinstance(data, list):
--> 509             data = list(data)
    510 
    511         if schema is None or isinstance(schema, (list, tuple)):

/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py in prepare(obj)
    680 
    681             def prepare(obj):
--> 682                 verify_func(obj)
    683                 return obj
    684         elif isinstance(schema, DataType):

/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py in verify(obj)
   1407     def verify(obj):
   1408         if not verify_nullability(obj):
-> 1409             verify_value(obj)
   1410 
   1411     return verify

/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py in verify_struct(obj)
   1384             elif isinstance(obj, (tuple, list)):
   1385                 if len(obj) != len(verifiers):
-> 1386                     raise ValueError(
   1387                         new_msg("Length of object (%d) does not match with "
   1388                                 "length of fields (%d)" % (len(obj), len(verifiers))))

ValueError: Length of object (1) does not match with length of fields (2)
```

I'm not understanding why it gives me "ValueError: Length of object (1) does not match with length of fields (2)" because I have specified 2 columns and looped through the values of each of the two columns.

When I put the variables "row_rdd_col_names" and "row_rdd_col_types" in the "data" variable in Parenthesis instead of brackets I get the two columns I want but I just get two rows for each column that says "undefined" if I use the "display()" function in Synapse Notebooks and "null" if I use ".show()", still not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
# Get each Columns name and data type from the original Dataframe 

"User_df":

col_types = User_df.dtypes

col_types2, col_types3 = [items[:] for items in zip(*col_types)]

rdd_col_names = sc.parallelize(col_types2)

rdd_col_types = sc.parallelize(col_types3)

row_rdd_col_names = rdd_col_names.map(lambda x: Row(x))

row_rdd_col_types = rdd_col_types.map(lambda x: Row(x))

data = [(row_rdd_col_names), (row_rdd_col_types)]

schema = StructType([StructField("ColumnNames", StringType(), True), 
                     StructField("ColumnDataTypes", StringType(), True)
                    ])

new_dataframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, schema) 

new_dataframe.show()

# The above code gives the following Result:

+-----------+---------------+
|ColumnNames|ColumnDataTypes|
+-----------+---------------+
|       null|           null|
|       null|           null|
+-----------+---------------+
```

Comment: if the dataframe is a spark dataframe, you could also use `spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_sdf.dtypes).toDF(['column_name', 'column_datatype'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the name and type of a spark dataframe as a spark dataframe, a single line code like the following would work.

For a spark dataframe `data_sdf`, the `.dtypes` will generate a list of tuples for column names and their types.

```python
data_sdf.dtypes

# [('event_id', 'string'),
#  ('cust_id', 'string'),
#  ('event_typ', 'string'),
#  ('event_ts', 'bigint'),
#  ('item_id', 'bigint'),
#  ('next_event_typ', 'string'),
#  ('prev_event_typ', 'string')]
```

Which means it can be directly converted to a spark dataframe.

```python
spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_sdf.dtypes).toDF(['column_name', 'column_datatype']). \
    show()

# +--------------+---------------+
# |   column_name|column_datatype|
# +--------------+---------------+
# |      event_id|         string|
# |       cust_id|         string|
# |     event_typ|         string|
# |      event_ts|         bigint|
# |       item_id|         bigint|
# |next_event_typ|         string|
# |prev_event_typ|         string|
# +--------------+---------------+
```

---

You can also use `createDataFrame()` that will result in the same output.

```python
spark.createDataFrame(data_sdf.dtypes, 'column_name string, column_datatype string'). \
    show()
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is way simpler than mine!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I'm posting this answer incase it helps anyone else:

```
# ".dtypes" gives a list of Tuples of your original Dataframes Columns & it's Data Types:

col_types = User_df.dtypes

# Loop through that list of tuples and Unpack it into the respective variables:

col_types2, col_types3 = [items[:] for items in zip(*col_types)]

# Below use zip(col_types2, col_types3) to create an iterator that produces tuples of form (x, y).

data = zip(col_types2, col_types3)

# Create the Schema: 

schema = StructType([StructField("ColumnNames", StringType(), True), 
                     StructField("ColumnDataTypes", StringType(), True)
                    ])

# Create the Dataframe:

new_dataframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, schema)  


new_dataframe.show(88, truncate = False)

new_dataframe.printSchema()

# Because the Dataframe has 88 columns I will only post a small sample of the result:

+----------------------------------------------+---------------+
|ColumnNames                                   |ColumnDataTypes|
+----------------------------------------------+---------------+
|Id                                            |string         |
|Date                                          |date           |
|Column1                                       |int            |
|Column2                                       |int            |
|Column3                                       |int            |
|Column4                                       |int            |
|Column5                                       |int            |
|Column6                                       |double         |
|Column7                                       |string         |
|Column8                                       |boolean        |
|Column9                                       |string         |
|Column10                                      |int            |
|Column11                                      |boolean        |
|Column12                                      |boolean        |
|Column13                                      |string         |
|Column14                                      |string         |
|Column15                                      |string         |
+----------------------------------------------+---------------+

root
 |-- ColumnNames: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ColumnDataTypes: string (nullable = true)
```